# no such option: --use-feature while installing tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I'm trying to install Tensorflow Object Detection API, following the steps at [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md), which is the official installation's documentation for Tensorflow 2.

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
> everything is ok
cd models/research/
> everything is ok
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
> everything is ok
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
> everything is ok
python -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .

> Usage:   
>   /opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/python -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-> index-options] ...
>   /opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/python -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
>   /opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
>   /opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
>   /opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/python -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

> no such option: --use-feature
```

Can someone help me understand why the installation stops as it does? I'm using macOS Mojave, Python 3.6 (on a conda virtual env), and Tensorflow 2.3.0.

Comment: Same problem here. Using Ubuntu.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu what pip version are u using?

Comment: 20.0.2. I upgraded it and the installations started.

Comment: Comments on this issue here : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md

Comment: @CatalinaChircu why 20.0.2? isn't the latest version 20.2.2?

Comment: I had 20.0.2 and upgraded to 20.2.2, then it worked. Now, I am on Ubuntu; I do not use conda and no venv. I just wonder if things would not be easier if using Tensorflow 1.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu upgraded to latest version... now it works! thanks a lot.

Comment: Put it in a comment too, for other people to find the answer if needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem, I upgraded pip version from 20.0.2 to 20.2.2, then it worked.

An issue was opened on github on this matter, check [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md).

Use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade pip.

Answer (score 5):

For the Tensorflow installation, you can simply remove this option and use:

```
python -m pip install .
```

Read [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#changes-to-the-pip-dependency-resolver-in-20-2-2020):

> pip 20.1 included an alpha version of the new resolver (hidden behind an optional --unstable-feature=resolver flag). pip 20.2 removes that flag, and includes a robust beta of the new resolver (hidden behind an optional --use-feature=2020-resolver flag) that we encourage you to test. We will continue to improve the pip dependency resolver in response to testers’ feedback. Please give us feedback through the resolver testing survey. This will help us prepare to release pip 20.3, with the new resolver on by default, in October.

Answer (score 3):

just needed to upgrade pip from version 20.0.2 to 20.2.2. An issue on github has also been opened ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md))

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and it worked

python -m pip install --user --use-feature=fast-deps .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).